# Start SQL Server from SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Is there a way to start SQL Server directly from SSMS?

I ask because I often go directly into SSMS, only to realize that I haven't started the SQL Server service yet. Which means either running a different app or messing around with the command prompt.

Comment: Remotely or locally?

Comment: Locally. It's my developer laptop (which is why SQL Server isn't set to auto-start.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start the SQL Server service from SSMS Registered Servers list (View-->Registered Servers). You might need to first register the desired server (local or remote).

Right-click on the registered name and select Service control-->Start.